# Bootstrap navbar expands incorrectly in mobile (narrow screen) view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, drop-down-menu

I'm following a video tutorial for Bootstrap. However, my bootstrap navbar expands and appears in mobile (narrow screens) next to the website logo. Relevant images:

1 - [Narrow screen view with menu expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGWSU.png)

In most normal websites it should appear under the logo.

2 - [Example of a Bootstrap website that has the correctly working mobile menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eueOd.png)

This is my code

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Share+Tech+Mono);

body {
    font-family: 'Share Tech Mono', monospace;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar {
    padding-top: 30px;    
    font-size: 26px;
    font-size-adjust: auto;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
}

.navbar-nav > li {
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.icon-bar {
    background-color: #000;
}

.row {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My website</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="">My Logo</a>
                
                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Main section of homepage -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row"></div> <div class="row"></div> <div class="row"></div>
            <div class="row"></div> <div class="row"></div>
        </div>
        
        <script src="js/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've forgotten wrapper to group brand and button:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
   <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navHeaderCollapse">
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="">My Logo</a>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle-example](https://jsfiddle.net/Igor_Ivancha/wfLhf7wt/)

Comment: Mate this is brilliant! Scratched my head a lot over this. I would upvote your answer if I had 15 rep :)